# Problema con el datetime en modelos de django rest framework

Tags: python, djangorestframework

Tengo un modelo simple para una tarea extraclase, necesito definir una hora inicial y hora final, lo hago usando el datetimefield, pero quiero que en mi panel de administracion solo me pida la hora para rellenar y como lo tengo tambien necesito poner el dia y no es lo que quiero, tambien me sucede que no se como definir el campo dias , el cual puede tener uno o varios dias de la semana, espero alguien pueda ayudarme a gatear por django-rest-framework

```
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
hora_inicio = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
hora_fin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno yo mismo me respondo , estaba enrredandome por guso respecto al tiempo ya que existe tambien un TimeField que me arregla la existencia. Sinembargo la parte del campo dias si necesito que alguien me ilumine

Comment: a lo del campo días te refieres a establecer un rango de fechas? o solo establecer un número de días, como diciendo, tal evento durara 3 días y lo que necesitas guardar en si un número(entero)?